# How to switch decimal and rounded whole number using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table that renders data from my Django app which uses PostgreSQL database.  How would I add a button to switch the Score column so it'll display the numbers between its original decimal value and rounded whole numbers?

Here is an example of what it would look like: https://jsfiddle.net/8a66gtww/

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="track_id"><input id="checkAll" type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="track_id"><input type="checkbox" name="track_id" value="2" /></td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Do</td>
            <td>65.85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="track_id"><input type="checkbox" name="track_id" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>88.25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="track_id"><input type="checkbox" name="track_id" value="4" /></td>
            <td>Donald</td>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>120.11</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
<br />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Switch</button> // Switches score between decimal and rounded whole number
```

Comment: Select the right td-element, extract the value, round it, write it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if it helps. I just modified your html a little for storing your score values so it can undo the round.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="track_id"><input id="checkAll" type="checkbox" /></th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="track_id"><input type="checkbox" name="track_id" value="2" /></td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Do</td>
            <td>65.85</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="65.85">
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="track_id"><input type="checkbox" name="track_id" value="1" /></td>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>88.25</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="88.25">
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="track_id"><input type="checkbox" name="track_id" value="4" /></td>
            <td>Donald</td>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>120.11</td>
            <input type="hidden" value="120.11">
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
<br />
<button class="switch">Switch</button>
```

and jquery is:

```
$('.switch').click(function () {
  $('.table tbody tr td:nth-child(4)').each(function() {

    if ($(this).html().indexOf('.') >= 0) {
        $(this).html(Math.round($(this).html()));
    } else {
        $(this).html($(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val());
    }
  });
});
```

It verifies if your score has the decimal dot. If the score is decimal, then it rounds it. If the score isn't decimal, it restores the original value.

https://jsfiddle.net/jdm3eovz/

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started:

```
<script>
window.switcher = {
    johnsScore: 0
}
switcher.switch = function(){
    var $johnsScore = $('tbody > tr td').eq(3)
    var $johnsCheckbox = $('tbody > tr input')
    if ($johnsCheckbox.prop('checked')) {
        if (this.johnsScore > 0) {
            $johnsScore.text(this.johnsScore)
            this.johnsScore = 0
        }
        else {
            this.johnsScore = $johnsScore.text()
            $johnsScore.text(Math.round(this.johnsScore))
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The button then changes to:

```
<button onclick="switcher.switch()">Switch</button>
```